# Total values from all keys in subdocument

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with documents that look like:

```
{
    '_id': 'doc1',
    'store_A': {'apples': 50, 'oranges':20},
    'store_B': {'oranges': 15}
}
{
    '_id': 'doc2',
    'store_A': {'oranges':10},
    'store_B': {'apples': 15}
}
```

**How can I write an aggregation command to give me the total number of fruits for each store across all documents in the collection WITHOUT enumerating all allowed kinds of fruit?**

The result should look like:

```
{
    '_id': 'Result',
    'store_A_total': {'apples': 50, 'oranges': 30},
    'store_B_total': {'apples': 15, 'oranges': 15}
}
```

This query works, but all the fruit types must be specified explicitly:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{'$group': {'_id': 'Result',
    'store_A_apples': {'$sum': '$Store_A.apples'},
    'store_A_oranges': {'$sum': '$store_A.oranges'},
    'store_B_apples': {'$sum': '$store_B.apples'},
    'store_B_oranges': {'$sum': '$store_B.oranges'}
}},
{'$project': {
    'store_A': {'apples': '$store_A_apples','oranges': '$store_A_oranges'},
    'store_B': {'apples': '$store_B_apples','oranges': '$store_B_oranges'}
}})
```

**Is there a better way to structure these documents to facilitate this type of query?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way in the mongodb aggregation framework for treating a
key inside of a document as data you can examine or manipulate. A
workaround is to turn what you're using as keys here (e.g. fruit type
and store name) into values like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "doc1",
    "stores":[
        {
            // store name is a value
            "name":"store_A",
            "inventory": [
            {
                // so is fruit type
                "type" : "apple",
                "count" : 50
            },
            {
                "type" : "orange",
                "count" : 20
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "store_B",
            "inventory": [
            {
                "type" : "orange",
                "count" : 15
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This allows you to work with these data more easily in aggregation:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    // split documents by store name
    {$unwind:"$stores"},
    // split documents further by fruit type
    {$unwind:"$stores.inventory"},
    // group documents together by store/fruit type, count quantities of fruit
    {$group:{"_id":{"store":"$stores.name", "fruit":"$stores.inventory.type"},
             "count":{$sum:"$stores.inventory.count"}}},
    // reformat the data to look more like your specification
    {$project:{
        "store":"$_id.store",
        "fruit":"$_id.fruit",
        "_id":0,
        "count":1}}])
```

The output looks like:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "count" : 15,
            "store" : "store_B",
            "fruit" : "apple"
        },
        {
            "count" : 15,
            "store" : "store_B",
            "fruit" : "orange"
        },
        {
            "count" : 30,
            "store" : "store_A",
            "fruit" : "orange"
        },
        {
            "count" : 50,
            "store" : "store_A",
            "fruit" : "apple"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```