# How do I query a hash sub-object that is dynamic in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I currently have a Question object and am not sure how to query for it?

```
{ "title" : "Do you eat fast food?"
"answers" : [
        {
            "_id" : "506b422ff42c95000e00000d",
            "title" : "Yes",
            "trait_score_modifiers" : {
                "hungry" : 1
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : "506b422ff42c95000e00000e",
            "title" : "No",
            "trait_score_modifiers" : {
                "not-hungry" : -1
            }
        }]
}
```

I am trying to find questions where the trait_score_modifieres is queried (sometimes it exists, sometimes not)

I have the following but it is not dynamic:

```
db.questions.find({"answers.trait_score_modifiers.not-hungry":{$exists: true}})
```

How could i do something like this?

```
db.questions.find({"answers.trait_score_modifiers.{}.size":{$gt: 0}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the schema so you have consistent key names to query on. I ran into a similar problem using the aggregation framework, see question: [Total values from all keys in subdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730501/total-values-from-all-keys-in-subdocument/18859716#18859716)

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
{
"title" : "Do you eat fast food?"
"answers" : [
        {
            "title" : "Yes",
            "trait_score_modifiers" : [
                {"dimension": "hungry", "value": 1}
            ]
        },
        {
            "title" : "No",
            "trait_score_modifiers" : [
                {"dimension": "not-hungry", "value": -1}
            ]
        }]
}
```

You can return all questions that have a dynamic dimension (e.g. "my new dimension") with:

```
db.questions.find("answers.trait_score_modifiers.dimension": "my new dimension")
```

Or limit the returned set to questions that have a specific value on that dimension (e.g. > 0):

```
db.questions.find(
    "answers.trait_score_modifiers": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "dimension": "my new dimension",
            "value": {"$gt": 0}
            }
        }

    )
```

Querying nested arrays can be a bit tricky, be sure to read up on the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-array/) In this case, `$elemMatch` is needed because otherwise you return a document that has some `trait_score_modifier` `my new dimension` but the matching `value` is in the `dimension` key of a different array element.

Answer (score 0):

You need $elemMatch criteria in your query.

Refer to: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/

Let me know if you need the query.